# Extract verbs and nouns using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to extract the nouns and verbs of a text but I'm getting a strange answer

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
text = nltk.word_tokenize("""Executam serviços de apoio nas áreas de recursos humanos, administração, finançase logística; atendem fornecedores e clientes, fornecendo e recebendo informações sobre produtos e serviços; tratam de documentos variados, cumprindo todo o procedimento necessário referente aos mesmos. atuam na concessão de microcrédito a  microempresários, atendendo clientes em campo e nas agências, prospectando clientes nas comunidades.""")
pos_tagged = nltk.pos_tag(text)
pos_tagged
NV = filter(lambda x:x[1]=='NN' or x[1] == 'VB',pos_tagged)
NV

[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /root/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!
[nltk_data] Downloading package averaged_perceptron_tagger to
[nltk_data]     /root/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package averaged_perceptron_tagger is already up-to-
[nltk_data]       date!
<filter at 0x7f0159c5f790>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
NV = list(filter(lambda x:x[1]=='NN' or x[1] == 'VB',pos_tagged))
```